# several minute delay after ssh connects before AWS Status Checks report success

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

We're trying reduce our AWS instance start up time.  We're able to ssh to an instance about 90 seconds after it starts.  But the Status Checks returns "initializing" until the instance has been running for over four minutes.  During that time I don't see the instance doing anything (top, vmstat, uptime all show the system basically idle).

Can anyone tell me how often the Status Check is run during instance start and what specifically its testing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Status Checks are performed every 60 seconds. And it performs different network tests along with making sure that an instance is started and configured properly.

You can read more on that in here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html

Comment: But my question remains: if I can ssh to the instance then the instance is up and reachable.  So why does it take another 3 minutes to get to status ok?